# Scrollbar popping and moving

Tags: css

Right now I'm using

```
body{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

in order to avoid the issue where when the scrollbar is not there, it pops in and moves the page to the left.

But it does not look so good with this solution, so I am curious what you do in order to circumvent this issue, if you have a more elegant solution, please share.

I'm looking for something that when the scrollbar becomes visible, it does not move the content, but without having it visible all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **hidden** property ?

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```